# How to make more beauty ruby code to count multiple items in flatten Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

I want to count how much `D` and `E` and `F` contains the array `ary` in total.

I can do it like

```
ary.count('D') + ary.count('E') + ary.count('F')
```

or like

```
count = 0
'DEF'.split('').each do |letter|
  count += ary.count(letter)
end
count
```

but both of it don't look very smart to me, is there a better way in ruby? Unfortunately, `.count('D','E','F')` does not work.

Comment: Is `ary` an array of 1-character strings? If not, and one element of `ary` is `"DDr"`, does that count as `0`, `1` or `2` `'D'`'s?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: well, if provided examples are any indication, then it's an array of one-char strings.

Comment: Ready to select an answer?

Comment: the problem is, my question somehow violated the stackoverflow question restrictions, thats why I cant accept an answer now because there is no real answer :)

Comment: This question is not on hold or otherwise closed or locked. I see no reason why you can't click the green checkmark by my answer (or one of the others :) )

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex.

```
ary.grep(/\A(D|E|F)\z/).size
```

You can easily build this regex from array `['D', 'E', 'F']`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Why the anchors? I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: @CarySwoveland To match single-letter strings and not, say, strings like `"F grade"`.

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward if you're simply counting letters:

```
letters = 'AEIOU'.chars

matches = 'FISSION'.chars.grep(Regexp.union(letters)).count
```

Where this is useful for matching single letter instances in a case-sensitive manner. Here `Regexp.union` creates a single regular expression that matches any of those letters.

Comment: that does not look simpler to me

Comment: A tiny suggestion: `'FISSION.each_char.grep...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why `each_char` vs. `chars`?

Comment: To avoid creating a temporary array. I'm in the habit of using `each_char` whenever an Enumerable follows.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, that is a good point. For repeat operations that'd be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a **block** to `Array#count`, as follows:

```
ary.count { |item| %w(D E F).include?(item) }
```

This will return a count of how many elements for which the block returns a truthy (not `nil` or `false`) value.

`%w()` is a nice syntax for defining an array of *strings* - i.e. the following are equivalent:

```
['D', 'E', 'F'] == %w(D E F)
```

Comment: Maybe just `'DEF'.include?(item)`.

Comment: Maybe, but this will also match "DE", "EF" and "DEF". If a strict single letter match is needed, this won't suffice

Comment: We need clarification. I left a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. It's actually very simple, using a little-known feature of `String#count`:

```
'DEF'.count('DEF') #=> 3
'FEED ME'.count('DEF') #=> 5
```